# <br> tags added automatically

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to design a page where user gives some information. I used table to style the form and I have no idea why are the 4 `<br/>` tags added every time I refresh the page. I tried both in **Firefox** and **Chrome** and the same thing happens. Also, there is no such tags in my source too. Below is the screenshot at my **Chrome** browser. Also, I'm using **PHP** for the development.

[image: Chrome Web Developer Tools]

**Update - Source code**

```
<div id="tt_entry">
                    <div id="theory_entry">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr><td class="width30 right">1st Subject: </td><td class="width70"><input id="t1" class="theory check_field" type="text"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="width30 right">2nd Subject: </td><td class="width70"><input id="t2" class="theory check_field" type="text"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="width30 right">3rd Subject: </td><td class="width70"><input id="t3" class="theory check_field" type="text"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="width30 right">4th Subject: </td><td class="width70"><input id="t4" class="theory check_field" type="text"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="width30 right">5th Subject: </td><td class="width70"><input id="t5" class="theory check_field" type="text"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="width30 right">6th Subject: </td><td class="width70"><input id="t6" class="theory check_field" type="text"></td></tr><br/>
                            <tr><td class="width30 right">Practical 1st Subject: </td><td class="width70"><input id="t1" class="practical check_field" type="text"></td></tr><br/>
                            <tr><td class="width30 right">Practical 2nd Subject: </td><td class="width70"><input id="t2" class="practical check_field" type="text"></td></tr><br/>
                            <tr><td class="width30 right">Practical 3rd Subject: </td><td class="width70"><input id="t3" class="practical check_field" type="text"></td></tr><br/>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <button id="next_button" class="button">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: If you want people to help with this you will have to show your source code in its raw form, not just what the developer tool shows it to be.

Comment: `<br/>` tags do not just appear out of the blue. We need to see the source code that outputs that section of the table.

Comment: bad question, incomplete, please give more information

Comment: The source code is different from the code in the screenshot of the DOM. Are you using any Javascript in your code that may be dynamically modifying the DOM?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Sadly that came out of the blue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<br>` tags are never added automaticly. By the way there are **4 `<br>` tags in the source code you added**, remove those and it should be fine.